# How to determine if Mac Update is stuck (on "Preparing Updates..")?

Tags: software-update

I am updating from `Sonoma 14.3` to `Sonoma 14.4`.  I've already waited more than 30 minutes a couple of times.  This is my third attempt.  Is there a way to see if this update is just slow or if it is actually stuck/hanging?

[image]

Here is the system info
[image]

Comment: What hardware is it? I would definitely favour leaving it, rather than force quitting the installation, which can be catastrophic.

Comment: @benwiggy  added screenshot : it is a well equipped 2019 model.   Is there anything even a dummy light for knowing if the update is progressing?  I hate being left in the dark.

Comment: Update would come via internet, yours might be very slow, but you could monitor the data transfer

Comment: You might also have a app that refuses to quit

Comment: @Ruskes  The download completed, it was the Preparing stage. It did finally complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update did complete, maybe at about an hour point (vs advertised 30 minutes).  There was no way to tell afaik whether it were hung or progressing.

Comment: The installer can’t predict the future with the time resolution we expect.

Comment: @IconDaemon  That is not the issue I posted about:  but rather about what is the *progress* (and is the update alive?)  It's about knowing whether I *should* wait or restart.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to tell, you just have to wait it out. Like it or not, an automated estimate of time remaining will always be inaccurate. It's always unwise to quit in the middle of a system install.

Comment: "always unwise".  I've heard stories of many hours.  This is not an acceptable mode of doing business: my time is a limited resource and not knowing how or if things are progressing is not acceptable.